# error while uploading file to IBM cloud object storage using python

Tags: python, cloud, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-storage

While running code in IDLE , it shows nothing.

```
from ibm_botocore.client import Config

import ibm_boto3

def upload_file(credentials,local_file_name,key):  
    cos = ibm_boto3.client(service_name='s3',
               ibm_api_key_id=credentials['got from service credential desciption'],

               ibm_service_instance_id=credentials['got from service credential description'],

               ibm_auth_endpoint=credentials['s3.eu-gb.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud'],//as my region is London

               config=Config(signature_version='oauth'),

               endpoint_url=credentials['https://control.cloud-object-storage.cloud.ibm.com/v2/endpoints'])

    try:
        res=cos.upload_file(Filename='D:\ibm-cloud\get-started-python\abc.txt', Bucket=credentials['cloud-college-bucket0'],Key=key)
    except Exception as e:
        print(Exception, e)
    else:
        print('File Uploaded')
```

Comment: Try to phrase your question in specific technical subquestions, ideally with code samples and problems you ran into.

Comment: Okay, I will. Thank you.

Comment: I modified my question with some code. Please help as soon as possible

Comment: Is this the real code? What is the error? If there is nothing, add debugging output.

Comment: Tried importing logging library of python and replacing all "print" with "logging.debug" but still the problem persists and no result is shown in IDLE.

Answer (score 0):

Your code defines a function, but is not calling it. Thus, the expected outcome or result is no output at all. Everything is just fine.

Your next step should be to have a main function or to have code on the upper level call into your defined function `upload_file`.

Comment: if __name__=='main':
    upload_file('cloud-college-bucket0','abc.txt')  **I added this at the end and removed the "key" arguement but I couldn't find anything on the output screen. **